# Differential Equation ODE

Tags: matlab

I have a problem with some differential equations of first-order. 
I'm trying to solve them with `ode23` and `ode23s`. 
The differential equations are:

y'+3y+z=0

z'-y+z=0

with the initial values:
y(0)=1 and z(0)=1

I also want to compare it with the analytical solution:

y=exp(-2x)(1-2x)

z=exp(-2x)(1+2x)

I want to do it this way because I need to do the comparison in order to choose the better solver: `ode23` or `ode23s`, whichever one is closer to the analytical solution.

My code is:

```
function dy=projectb1(t,y)

%y'=-4y

%z'= 0
%y(1)=y'
%y(2)=z'

dy = [-4*y(2); 0*y(1)];
```

and:

```
% Comparison of analytical solution
clear

options= odeset('RelTol',1e-4,'AbsTol', [1e-4 1e-4]); 

%figure
%t1=cputime;

[t23,y23]= ode23('projectb1',[0 12],[1 1],options);

[t23s,y23s]= ode23s('project1',[0 20],[1 0],options);

%tobl = cputime -t1

figure

ya=exp(-2*t23).*(1-2*t23);

za=exp(-2*t23).*(1+2*t23);

plot(t23,ya,za,'r',t23,y23(:,1),'g-.',t23s,y23s(:,1),'b');

%legend('ya','ode23','ode23s',0)
text(3.4,-1.7,'ya')

title('\bf{Analytical and numerical solutions using} \it{ode23s, ode23}')
```

But it doesn't work. Could someone help me?

Comment: Because i try to plot it:

figure

ya=(exp(-2*t23)).*(1-2*t23);

za=(exp(-2*t23)).*(1+2*t23);

plot(t23,za,t23,ya);

figure

plot(t23,y23(:,1),'g-.',t23s,y23s(:,1),'b');


 but they are very different from the Analytical equations

Answer (score 0):

The error Matlab throws right away has to do with the line

```
plot(t23,ya,za,'r',t23,y23(:,1),'g-.',t23s,y23s(:,1),'b');
```

This should be

```
plot(t23,ya,t23,za,'r',t23,y23(:,1),'g-.',t23s,y23s(:,1),'b');
```

You missed that extra `t23`.

---

Another problem appears to be in the definition of the differential equation.
For systems of differential equations, the Matlab ODE suite passes a vector `x` whose components are the values of the functions you are attempting to approximate.
Therefore, as in the example below, the first component of `x` is the value of `y` at time `t`, and the second component of `x` is the value of `z` at time `t`:

```
function dx = projectb1(t,x)
    y = x(1);
    z = x(2);

    dy = -3*y - z;
    dz =    y - z;

    dx = [dy;dz];
end
```

I changed the input `y` to `x` to make it clear that what is input is a vector of values of `y` and `z`.

---

Also, note that while `ode23` has the initial conditions `[1,1]`, `ode23s` has `[1,0]`, which means it is solving a different initial value problem.

Comment: I fixed it!! THANK YOU!!!! @TroyHaskin

I have the last question, if I had this initial values y(pi)=1 and z(pi)=1, how would I do it?

Comment: The time of the initial condition is determined by the time span you give the ODE solver.  So if your initial data is at `pi`, the ODE input would be `[t23,y23]= ode23('projectb1',[pi 12],[1 1],options);`

Comment: OHHH, thank you.Do you know how could i solve the same equation in simulink? @TroHaskin

Comment: @mmmtt That I do not know how to do.

Comment: thnk u anyway @TroHaskin

Comment: Why would you want to use simulink? With Troy's 3 fixes, everything works correctly.